# php Access an object value

Tags: php, object, foreach

```
stdClass Object
(
    [request] => stdClass Object
        (
            [other] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [answer] => one
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [answer] => two
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [answer] => three
                        )
                )

        )
)
?>
```

I'm able to print out all the answers by looping with a foreach.

```
foreach( $result->request->other as $test )
      $tests[] = $test->answer;
            foreach($tests as $test1){
            echo "<p>$test1</p><br>";
          }
```

I'm a little confused on how to also echo out the answer number which in this case is 4 5 6. How do i echo them out as part of the loop. ex:

```
4 one
5 two
6 three
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `foreach( $array AS $key=>$val )` syntax, like this:

```
foreach( $result->request->other as $key=>$test ) {
  printf( "<p>%s: %s</p><br />", $key, $test->answer );
}
```

Comment: This echos out the last number on all the answers. ex: `6 one 6 two 6 three`. This is wrong it should echo out `4 one 5 two 6 three`. What is causing this to happen

Comment: it shouldn't. I also simplified the code as there's no point of doing `foreach()` more than once. Check it now

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $result->request->other as $key => $test )
      $tests[] = $test->answer;
            foreach($tests as $test1){
            echo "<p>$test1</p><br>";
          }
```

Simply change the foreach line to include a $key => before the $test variable.  This will be the index (numeric or associative), and you can get that value and do as you like with it.